# How to record remote feed in local system using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I've tried to record remote feed using MediaStream, MediaRecorder, RecordRTC, but I'm unable to record remote feed. I am able to record local camera feed. Does anyone know how I can record remote feed using JavaScript?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What goes wrong with your previous attempts?

Comment: what is the difference between a remote camera feed and local camera feed in your application ?

Comment: The difference between remote camera feed and local camera feed is the remote camera feed is coming from server and the local camera feed is coming from in webcam which is connected in local system.

for example we both are connected via video call, so I want to record your camera feed at my end.